# ngx-modialog not center when use open method

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I am opening a modal in agular 7 with the ngx-modialog library as follows

```
import { Modal } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

this.modal.open(WorkloadDetailHistoryModalComponent, overlayConfigFactory({
          size: 'lg',
          scope: this
        }));
```

but the modal comes out in one of the corners of the page and not in the center.
How can I make it come out centered?

just let me add a custom class but I haven't managed to do it :(

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

add parameter 'dialogClass' in overlayConfigFactory ¬¬

```
this.modal.open(WorkloadDetailHistoryModalComponent,
 overlayConfigFactory({
       size: 'lg',
       scope: this,
       dialogClass: 'modal-dialog'
     }));
```